# Visual Basic 6 clear contents in text file without referencing a library6

Tags: vb6

I'm wondering how I could delete all contents in a text file using VB6 without needing to add a reference to any object libraries.
Unfortunately, all I know is how to open it:

```
Open App.Path & "/media/text.txt" For Input As #1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dim intFile As Integer

intFile = FreeFile

Open App.Path & "/media/text.txt" For Output As #intFile
Close #intFile
```

used [this](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/how-read-simple-text-files) as a quickref